# How to create a REST services using Node.JS in Raspberry PI?

Tags: raspbian, node.js, sqlite, database

I would like to seek help on how to create a REST services using Node.JS in Raspberry PI. A simple REST services which can gather data from the sensors and write to SQLite database or Windows Azure's SQL Database. Hardware I will be using is Raspberry PI.

Comment: You want to collect sensor data locally on the RPi and then make them available via REST using NodeJS? Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, Marco Poli.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first install the node.js package compatible with ARM:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.26/node-v0.10.26-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz
tar -xvzf node-v0.10.26-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz
```

Now add this to your .bash_profile

```
NODE_JS_HOME=/home/pi/node-v0.10.26-linux-arm-pi
PATH=$PATH:$NODE_JS_HOME/bin
```

[source](http://joshondesign.com/2013/10/23/noderpi)

From there you can install [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) which you can use for your api

Comment: I just followed your steps and installed, hagope. What should I do next?

Comment: @user3127380 we aren't going to code your project for you, you need to do it yourself. We can help you with the Pi-specific bits, but ultimately you need to do the bulk of the work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial of how to use express 4 (last version so far), this is an amazing module, it provides a lot of power, just what you are looking for

Node.js + express + rest + mondoDB

http://webapplog.com/express-js-4-node-js-and-mongodb-rest-api-tutorial/